# RxJava Observable Single show current thread

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

I'm trying to understand how observable works and I'd like to show the current thread to get a better understanding. The whole app is built with java 8 and make use of lambda expressions. No having much experience with it I'm finding some troubles to show my current thread in an expression like this:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())                          
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.flatMap(..... -> {
```

I like to put something like this:

```
log.info("Current Thread:", Thread.currentThread().name)
```

But I couldn't find a way to do it as subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) and observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) return and Single and there is no way to put something like this:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.log.info("Current Thread:", Thread.currentThread().name)
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.log.info("Current Thread:", Thread.currentThread().name)
.flatMap(..... -> {
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying just to log the current Thread, correct?

Just use `map` for log and return the same value:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(it -> {
    log.info("Current Thread:", Thread.currentThread().name)
    return it;
})
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(it -> {
    log.info("Current Thread:", Thread.currentThread().name)
    return it;
})
.flatMap(..... -> {
```

Comment: Or use .doOnNext, then you don't have to return it again.